# How to programmatically expand or collapse Tree Item in Material Ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there any way to programmatically expand and collapse tree items in material ui? I can do that by clicking on the item, but there are other times when I would like to collapse and expand the tree items based on an action in the tree view. is it possible?

Comment: Finding for the same answer. were you able to find the solution?

Comment: It seems that you can do so using `TreeView`'s `onNodeToggle` and `expanded` properties. Take a look into the _Controlled_ example for `TreeView` component [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/tree-view/)

Comment: Calling `setExpanded` with your desired expand node id should do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve that using TreeView `expanded` prop. 
The code below expands the TreeItem with id "1" on mount.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import TreeView from '@material-ui/lab/TreeView';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import TreeItem from '@material-ui/lab/TreeItem';

export default function FileSystemNavigator() {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setExpanded(["1"])
  },[])

  return (
    <TreeView
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
      expanded={expanded}
    >
      <TreeItem nodeId="1" label="Applications"    
>
        <TreeItem nodeId="2" label="Calendar" />
        <TreeItem nodeId="3" label="Chrome" />
        <TreeItem nodeId="4" label="Webstorm" />
      </TreeItem>
      <TreeItem nodeId="5" label="Documents"
>
        <TreeItem nodeId="6" label="Material-UI">
          <TreeItem nodeId="7" label="src">
            <TreeItem nodeId="8" label="index.js" />
            <TreeItem nodeId="9" label="tree-view.js" />
          </TreeItem>
        </TreeItem>
      </TreeItem>
    </TreeView>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-txzis?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: what if I only want the selected parent TreeItem to be selected while collapsing the others? like when I select node 1, then node 6 collapses ?

Answer (score 4):

This answer is for [Riham Nour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5511197/riham-nour) Question in the comment section of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59123864/7455897) (won't be able to reply in comments due to less reputation).

> what if I only want the selected parent TreeItem to be selected while
> collapsing the others? like when I select node 1, then node 6
> collapses ?

Just add the nodeId of the selected nodes then you can easily be able to get the desired outcome. You can go through the code [Code SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-sre9c).

PS: I hope I understood the question correctly and Sorry I added this in the answer section. Please let me know if there is any better way to communicate the answer to Riham.

Answer (score 0):

We can maintain an array of expanded items in state and pass it to TreeView. And simply onNodeSelect we can add and remove expended items in array.

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState([]);

<TreeView
      expanded={expanded}
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
      onNodeSelect={(event, nodeId) => {
        const index = expanded.indexOf(nodeId);
        const copyExpanded = [...expanded];
        if (index === -1) {
          copyExpanded.push(nodeId);
        } else {
          copyExpanded.splice(index, 1);
        }
        setExpanded(copyExpanded);
      }}
    >
      <TreeItem nodeId="1" label="Applications">
    <TreeItem nodeId="2" label="Calendar" />
    <TreeItem nodeId="3" label="Chrome" />
    <TreeItem nodeId="4" label="Webstorm" />
  </TreeItem>
  <TreeItem nodeId="5" label="Documents">
    <TreeItem nodeId="6" label="Material-UI">
      <TreeItem nodeId="7" label="src">
        <TreeItem nodeId="8" label="index.js" />
        <TreeItem nodeId="9" label="tree-view.js" />
      </TreeItem>
    </TreeItem>
  </TreeItem>
</TreeView>
```