# React MUI TreeView / React DnD: How to use a draggable component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, treeview, react-dnd

In my React web app, I would like to

1. drag items from the [MUI TreeView](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tree-view) on the left to one of the drop targets on the right
2. drag and drop items between the drop targets

UI mockup:

[image: MUI TreeView UI mockup]

The second part already works.

As for the first part, I did manage to make them draggable (following the [React DnD Basic Example](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/hooks-overview#basic-example)) and I can drag them from the tree view into the drop targets:

```js
const DraggableTreeItem = (props: TreeItemProps) => {
  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
    collect: (monitor: DragSourceMonitor) => ({
      isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
    }),
    item: props,
    type: MyDnDItemType
  })
  return (
    <TreeItem ref={drag} {...props}/>
  )
}

export default DraggableTreeItem;
```

**My problem:** I would like the items in the tree view to look the same as in the drop targets to maintain some "UI coherence", i.e. make it visually immediately obvious that those are the same items: Instead of just the MUI "built-in" simple string, I'd like the same item box with a colored icon (and a string): Seems to me I should ideally use the same component throughout.

I've messed around with the [ContentComponent prop](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tree-view/#contentcomponent-prop) example in the MUI TreeView docs, but it seems to me that when I take that approach, I need to re-implement (i.e. duplicate) a lot of the built-in tree functionality (expanding nodes, collapsing, selecting, etc.).

I've also tried to make sense of the MUI TreeView docs [Gmail clone](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tree-view/#gmail-clone) example, but there seems to be so much unrelated stuff in there that I don't see the forest for all the trees. Also, I am not sure if this MUI `styled(TreeItem)(({ theme })` concept is intended for what I want to achieve.

**My question:** How can I use my own (draggable) component as tree view item ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution: The [MUI TreeView API docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tree-item) don't seem to mention that, but the `TreeItem` `label` prop can be a simple string (as it often is) - or an entire component, for example my custom component:

```js
<TreeView >
  <TreeItem label={ <MyComponent/> } nodeId="1"/>
</TreeView>
```

Well, technically, the docs do state `node` as type for the `TreeView` `label` prop, but that really seems like the kind of info you only see once you already know it - and *The tree node label.* as description really sounds like a string and not like a component.

The UI now looks like this:

[image: MUI TreeView UI mockup]

Comment: When I try to implement such a solution, my components rendered in the tree are not draggable. If I render my component not in the tree, but in any other place in the DOM it is draggable. I believe some click handler on the tree is intersepting drag operations. Could you, please, share some code example how does it work in your case?

Comment: @SergeyPanov: Sorry, code is proprietary, not allowed to share. Also, haven't worked on this for a long time; trying to give you the pointers I somewhat manage to remember: Dragging within the right hand side UI section works, but dragging from the left to the right does not work - at least not on any browser except Firefox. I [posted to MUI Issues](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/9686) back then, but the issue never really got a lot of attention. I'll have to get back on this some time soon; for the moment, please take what I write with a grain of salt.