# ReactJS: How to collapse Material UI TreeView after expanding?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I have a material UI `treeView`. When I expand it, it hits a API. But after pressing the expand button, the `treeView` node remains opened. I have tried using `onNodeToggle` but nothing seems to work.

Here is my code:

```
<TreeView
  className={classes.root1}
  defaultExpandIcon={<ArrowDropDownIcon />}
  defaultCollapseIcon={<ArrowDropUpIcon />}
  defaultEndIcon={<ArrowDropDownIcon />}
  disableSelection={true}
  expanded={expanded}
  collapsed={expanded}
>
  {renderTree(row, index)}
</TreeView>;
```

How to collapse it?. Any fix for this?. Is it possible in Material UI treeView?.

Comment: can you please share demo code link?

Comment: yes sure. I'm sharing

Comment: I guess the answer could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57742324/how-to-programmatically-expand-or-collapse-tree-item-in-material-ui)

Comment: No. My issue is once I expand it, the expanded node never collapses. How to fix this?? Is there any fix for this?. I have already checked the page you are pointing at

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this props, isn't it?

```
expanded={expanded}
collapsed={expanded}
```

1. `collapsed` is not in the documenatation
2. `expanded` is array of the expanded items. If you want to collapse item just remove it from this array.

Controlled TreeView docs
https://material-ui.com/components/tree-view/#ControlledTreeView.js

Comment: It's not working with collapsed. Can you please create a sandbox of it???

Comment: The problem is I'm not able to collapse it. The useState is used to set the data of every node expand. When the API hits, it changes the state and shows the node. But what I'm using is, I'm showing all the nodes whatever it may be in the state while collapsing other nodes. So, it would be one node expand at a time. I want to expand one node and collapse others. And once I expand it, I'm unable to collapse it again. Do you have any fix for this??

Comment: If you use expanded prop it means you controls with it which nodes are expanded (array of ids), so if you want to collapse some node, you have to control it by yourself. (send to expanded prop array of newly expanded items = remove the collapsed one from it)

Comment: Try to log this array or to update it manually and watch how does it behaves.